# Remote Alarm Broadcast Communicating data

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to have a periodic polling mechanism to detect new orders (after the last order the user has seen) for which
I have setup a couple of broadcast recievers(one for boot activate,and other for executing recurring task) and a service.I use Alarmmanager to periodically call the **PeriodicTaskReciever**.

Now I need to know how to communicate with such a  remote broadcast reciever(A flag parameter indicating the last user seen order needs updation). I've tried shared preferences and as indicated in a lot of articles remote process is unable to read updated values of SP

```
<service android:name=".OrderService" />
        <receiver android:name=".BootReciever" >
            <intent-filter>    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <receiver android:name=".PeriodicTaskReciever"
        android:process=":remote"
        />
```

My PeriodicTask Reciever is

```
public class PeriodicTaskReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{ private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    static int lastOrder;
    int NOTIFICATION_COUNTID=100;
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("DataHandlerService",  "Service hbeat");
        if(intent.getIntExtra("update",0)!=0){
            lastOrder=intent.getIntExtra("update",0);
            Log.d("DataHandlerService",  "Last order updated");
        }
        else{
            if(Utils.isNetworkAvailable(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext())){
                Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder();
                uri.scheme("http");
                uri.authority(Constants.URL_API_HOST);
                uri.path(Constants.URL_API_ORDERPATH);


                uri.appendQueryParameter("lastorder",getLastOrderFromSharedPref());
                String url=uri.build().toString();
                Log.d("DataHandlerService",  "Service hbeat"+url);

                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(url,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        try {
                            if(!jsonObject.isNull("status") && jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")){

                                if(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("data"))>0){

                                    displayNotification("You have "+ Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("data"))+ " new orders ",context);
                                }}
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }


                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    }
                });

                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest,"PollOrders");}}
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, PeriodicTaskReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 , pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PeriodicTaskReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
```

Am I misusing the remote. I need to notify users pretty much from the background when my app isnt running. And once the users click on a notification or dismiss it the lastOrder value gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no work of `android:process=":remote"` for a `BroadcastReceiver`. So remove that and here you are no using `intent-filter` for receiver so you need  to `export` that `BroadcastReceiver`.

---

Instead of doing

```
<receiver android:name=".PeriodicTaskReciever"
        android:process=":remote"
        />
```

export your receiver. like

```
<receiver android:name=".PeriodicTaskReciever"
        android:exported="true"
        />
```

Comment: Could you highlight how one must communicating if its a remote service lets say.Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I did not get your confusion. Please explain more :)

Comment: So exported works fine but I just wanted to know how in general does one communicate with a component running in a different process defined by say :remote (say a service) .Basically passing data to and fro with a different process component .Is it just AIDL?

Comment: Look here remote used for service only. There are several ways to communicate between IPC like Intents, AIDL.